# converting objective c to swift - GameKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, game-center

I'm in the process of converting some objective c to swift and I'm stuck on a line that I don't understand:

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
```

The part that confuses me is the caret and what comes after it:

```
^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
```

more importantly, I'd like to understand what the line means (in addition to its swift conversion)

Comment: It's a block. Here's the swift equivalent https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a block. The Swift equivalent could look like this

```
let handler: (UIViewController, NSError) -> Void = { (controller, error) in
    ...
}
```

Comment: so I can say `localPlayer.authenticateHanlder = handler` ? where `handler` is the variable you set above?

Answer (score 4):

It's a [block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH3-SW1) - it is just like a C function which you can use as a variable (for example, when assigning a property).

The equivalent concept in Swift is called a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). Fortunately for you, they are [compatible](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID49) - you can pass Swift closures to Objective-C methods and properties which expect blocks.

Answer (score 2):

It's an Objective-C block. Which in Swift would translate to the following closure:

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = { 
    (viewController: UIViewController, error: NSError) in

    }
```

Not that complex.

Although you could still use [iSwift](http://iswift.org) and have it converted automatically. :)

Comment: thanks for iSwift reference, that will come in handy